# Anyone know why it gives me error or how solve this?

Tags: google-sheets

in practice I want to SUM only when B3 is equal to B4
if B3 is less than B4, B4 remains the same but if B3 becomes bigger than B4, B4 WILL BE EQUAL TO B3.

Also I don't want to make sure that if I add a negative number like -10 $ B4 it goes down in value.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI7vJ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **a circular reference** in your formula. Formulas in google sheets can calculate only with values actually on the sheet.

In figure below:
The `B4` cell contains the formula: `=MAX(D13:D29);`.
And the area `D13:D29` is filled by formula: `=SUM($B$13:B13)`.

[image: Helping data in the column D]

Values from question:
[image: Better set of values]

Comment: Well it works but it doesn't do what I want ....

Comment: I want to do like this "in practice I want to SUM only when B3 is equal to B4 if B3 is less than B4, B4 remains the same but if B3 becomes bigger than B4, B4 WILL BE EQUAL TO B3."  
Also if I put a negative value I don't want B4 to calculate it.

Comment: @CesareCentritto what means B4 remains the same? B4 is formula.

Comment: Ex if B3 is less than B4 B4 will not change in value

Comment: @CesareCentritto I don't know the value of B4. The formula states the value.

Comment: Ex B4 is equal to $ 200 and B3 to $ 200
If below I put -10 $ B3 becomes 190 $ but B4 remains the same if I add another type number + 15 $ B3 becomes 205 and B4 in turn becomes 205 and so on B4 is like the total sum (biggest ever) and B3 is that current.

Comment: Basically it's like a bank account, B3 is what I have at the moment and B4 is the biggest amount I've had in the bank.

Comment: Everything will start from 0 of course

Comment: @CesareCentritto Now I understand. But as I know, formulas only count with actual numbers in a sheet. There is a scripting tool for changing cells.

Comment: So are you telling me it's not possible to do this?

Comment: Or how can I deal with that thing you tell me "scripting tool for changing cells"

Comment: @CesareCentritto You are adding values to Prezzo sekventially (from up to down)? So You try to find max from sum(B13:??)?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: I put values ​​only down in ("anno 2021"<--- Year 2021*) and above them I want them to calculate me automatically

Comment: @CesareCentritto  As you mentioned above, that you try to find maximal amount of account. So If in prezzo is history of your account history, so you can find the maxum.

Comment: Calculate type:

Current Heritage  (B3)
   and
Highest estate ever (B4).

Comment: Try to put C13: =sum($B$13:B13) and copy down until C29. Then you will have there historical balances of your account. Then you can use =MAX(C13:C29) in your B4.

Comment: "@CesareCentritto As you mentioned above, that you try to find maximal amount of account. So If in prezzo is history of your account history, so you can find the maxum"

Comment: Yes like this ^

Comment: Where I ned to put this? C13: =sum($B$13:B13)

Comment: =sum($B$13:B13) to C13 copy it to clipboard and then mark C13:C29 and paste from clipboard.

Comment: what is clipboard?

Comment: Menu Edit -> Copy.

Comment: Do you have discord or telegram so I share the document? If it's not a bother for you?

Comment: https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/googlespreadsheets/types-of-cell-references/1/

Comment: So you want that i make a copy of sheets and share to you here?

Comment: I've edit my answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: Take advantage of absolute and relative references mentioned in the link above.

Comment: Then yes more or less it is just like that, if B3 is less than B4, B4 MUST NOT INCREASE IN VALUE.
How do i do this?

Comment: https://imgur.com/FQANmeE

Comment: As from the image 80 it had to have a value of 70.

Comment: But in turn if I add a negative value below, B4 MUST NOT DECREASE IN VALUE

Comment: I solved this "But in turn if I add a negative value below, B4 MUST NOT DECREASE IN VALUE" with this formula  =SUMIF(B13:B28, ">0"),  
But at the same time, I don't know how to fix this  "Then yes more or less it is just like that, if B3 is less than B4, B4 MUST NOT INCREASE IN VALUE. How do i do this?" & "As from the image 80 it had to have a value of 70"

Comment: I recommend creating an auxiliary range with a balance. In my example D13:D29 (=sum($B$13:B13)). You'd rather keep auxiliary values on the second sheet so that they do not disturb the appearance of the main worksheet. I put the auxiliary values so that you can see them on the screenshots.